# TypeError: firebase.INTERNAL.registerComponent is not a function at configureForFirebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-firestore

#### 1. Problem

I am running *npm start* which is building my react-firebase application, which compiles fine but when I look at my app on localhost I receive this error:

[Build Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE0Ys.png)

#### 2. What I've Done

- I tried to follow suggestions in this Github [post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/722).
- I noticed that by going to node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:27457:21 and changing **firebase.INTERNAL.registerComponent** to **firebase.INTERNAL.registerComponent** this changed the error to **TypeError: instance.registerVersion is not a function** which makes me believe that there must be some issue with my version of firebase.
- I have tried to revert firebase to version 7.6.0 since there was a recent update made on 01/09/2020 to no avail.
- I tried doing all the installing of dependencies in a virtual environment just in case, for some reason, there were some discrepancies between projects

**First Error Location:**

```
function configureForFirebase(firebase) {
    firebase.INTERNAL.registerComponent(new component.Component('firestore', function (container) {
        var app = container.getProvider('app').getImmediate();
        return new Firestore(app, container.getProvider('auth-internal'));
    }, "PUBLIC" /* PUBLIC */).setServiceProps(shallowCopy(firestoreNamespace)));
}
```

**Second Error location:**

```
function registerFirestore(instance) {
    configureForFirebase(instance);
    instance.registerVersion(name, version);
}
```